# Substring extraction from java

Tags: java, string

I have a string enclosed between curly braces like this `{X,X},{Y,Y},{Z,Z}`
I want to extract string along with the braces so that the output will be

```
String 1={X,X}
String 2={Y,Y}
String 3={Z,Z}
```

Comment: but @NitinBisht, it will produce the output like `{X` `X}` `{Y`... and not `{X, X}` `{Y,Y}`...

Comment: @ganjaam it will produce {X,X} {Y,Y} and {Z,Z}, try it

Comment: @NitinBisht what does the following display: `System.out.println(s.split(",").length)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be split with the following [regexp `"\\s*,\\s*(?![^{}]*\\})"` with negative look-ahead](https://regex101.com/r/Bo5V53/1):

```
String s = "{ X, X }, {Y,Y} , {Z,Z}";

// s.split(",(?![^{}]*\\})"); // version that keeps whitespaces

String[] split = s.split("\\s*,\\s*(?![^{}]*\\})"); // added handling of optional whitespaces
System.out.println(split.length + " -> ");
Arrays.stream(split).forEach(System.out::println);
```

output:

```
3 -> 
{ X, X }
{Y,Y}
{Z,Z}
```

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to use a regex expression since as you know, you can't just use the split function.

You can use the following regex expression to split apart the strings you want:

```
{[^,]+(,)[^,]+}
```

For more information on regex, visit https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html
For testing out this regex expression, visit https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 0):

Replace the commas separating the pairs within braces by another character that is not a comma, for example a period. Then split the string by that character.

```java
String str = "{X,X},{Y,Y},{Z,Z}";
String tmp = str.replace("},{", "}.{");
System.out.println(tmp);
String[] elems = tmp.split("\\.");
for (int i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(elems[i]);
}
```

Comment: Tried that way but getting this error , 
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition near index 1
},{

Comment: @Jagan the parameters in method [`replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-) of class `java.lang.String` are not regular expressions. I'm guessing that you are calling method `replaceAll` and not method `replace`.